# When can a k-form be expressed as a wedge product of one forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Suppose I am handed a k-form $\omega$. What can I do to check if $\omega$ can be expressed in the form

$$\omega = \alpha_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \alpha_k?$$

The context for this question is an application in differential geometry. A codimension-k surface is characterized by a k-form field of the above form; I am trying to ascertain when a specified k-form field defines a codimension-k surface

EDIT: An equivalent question is, "when is a given k-form the unique top-level form of some k-dimensional subspace?"

Comment: @cmk I'm not sure what you mean by this. I think the statement I'm making should be basis-independent.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A wedge of 1 forms without superpositions? If this is true that's good news, but I'm surprised. In R4, how can $dx \wedge dy + dz \wedge dw$ be expressed as a wedge product of 1 forms?

Comment: Briefly, you need to have $\omega \wedge \iota_v\omega = 0$ for every element of a basis set of vectors $v$.

Comment: What if $\omega$ is a $d/2+1$ or higher form in a d-dimensional space? Then just by counting your condition is trivially satisfied. Does this suggest that any sufficiently high-rank form can be written in the form I suggested in my question?

Comment: Also, what if $\omega$ itself is a one-form? Then your condition seems untrue at least naively.

Comment: See also> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834648/is-a-pointwise-decomposable-differential-form-smoothly-decomposable